# Show profile2 fields only to specific user register path

Tags: users

I am interested in showing profile2 fields only to specific user register path (I have 2 user register path).
How can I do this without using the Profile2 registration path module as another module creates the paths?
thanks

Comment: did u find any solution

Answer (score 0):

You could apply that patch to **profile2_regpath.module** which simply show all profile fields to its registeration patch [posted here](https://www.drupal.org/node/2489324#comment-10304107)